# Code for draw multiplication table according to user input but condition is that user input line is skip

Tags: java

I tried following code

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Table {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            System.out.println("Enter number");
            int b = sc.nextInt();
            {

                for(int i =1; i<=10; i++){
                    if (i==b)
                        System.out.println();
                    else
                        System.out.println(b+" * "+i+" = "+b*i);
                    sc.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Please Enter Valid Number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: explain your error. add some text, compile output, console output. what you see and what you expect to see

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow - nobody will ever be able to decipher your intentions or even guess your acual question correctly (since you didnt write one), please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite hard to understand, so please correct me if I got it wrong.

**Your expectation:**

1. User inputs a single (?) number
2. 10 lines are printed, each displaying the users number multiplicated with the line number

**Your problem:**

One line of your output is skipped.

**Solution:**

Input between 1 to 10 will output one empty line due to

```
if (i==b)
System.out.println();
```

Your loop should look like this:

```
for(int i =1; i<=10; i++)
{
    System.out.println(b+" * "+i+" = "+b*i);
}
sc.close();
```